# Display calendar availability in flutter using table_calendar, icalendar_parser and http

Tags: flutter, http, icalendar, table-calendar

How to display calendar availability in flutter like similiar AIRBNB?

I dont know how to display json data to event `table_calendar`

I already combine code from package `icalendar_parser` and `http`, I use http for url and convert that string to json using `icalendar_parser` but i dont know how to display that json to event `table_calendar`. i want like this
[Calendar Availability AIRBNB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXjrq.png)

this my code read ical feed url using 'http' package and 'icalendar_parser' package to convert data to 'JSON'

[This My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azUuT.png)

And this output from convert data string ical to JSON
[Data JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaXu6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the exact same calendar. But better to try [simple_vertical_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_vertical_calendar)